# How to clear search textbox in primeng multiselect

Tags: angular, primeng

Is there anyway to clear primeng multiselect search textbox value?

I'm following below article for primeng multiselect.

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/multiselect

[image]

I want to clear Multiselect search textbox value `Item 1` which is highlighted above.

I want to clear value programmatically. Is there any property or code to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add   `resetFilterOnHide=true` to `<p-multiSelect>`.

It should fix issue.